# How can I stop an application from being deployed twice in Tomcat (one in root context and one in application context)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I am running a maven application on a local Tomcat 8 server using Tomcat-Maven-Plugin.
The problem is that the application is being deployed twice.
Once in the Tomcat root directory (`http://localhost:8080`) and once on its own context directory (`http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/`).
I can use the tomcat manager app at `http://localhost:8080/manager` to manually stop the application from running at the root directory but I wonder if there is a setting in Tomcat 8 that can have the same result.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is not normally going to deploy your application twice.  If it happens, it's almost certainly due to a misconfiguration.  The common source of double deployments is invalid / incorrect `path` attribute on your Context.  Look for a `META-INF/context.xml` file in your app or perhaps something in your Maven deployment configuration that's trying to set the path.

See the `path` attribute [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) for more info on this.